# "Ein" anstatt "einen" – "Wir haben ein Kurzfilm gedreht"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, accusative

Folgendes, ich sehe häufig Fehler der folgenden Art:

> Wir haben ein Kurzfilm gedreht.

Es müsste natürlich **einen** heißen; allerdings weiß ich erfahrungsgemäß, dass manche Leute sich dieses Fehlers überhaupt nicht bewusst sind (vermutlich, weil man das "en" in der gesprochenen Sprache oft verschluckt). Ich wüsste gerne, wie ich gut erklären könnte, warum *ein* an der Stelle falsch ist. Soweit ich weiß, müsste es immer "einen" heißen, wenn man im Akkusativ von einem männlichen Substantiv schreibt. Ist das korrekt? Und kennt Ihr irgendwelche etwas zugänglicheren Faustregeln o. Ä., anhand derer sich dieser Fehler leicht vermeiden lässt?

Comment: "dass manche Leute sich dieses Fehlers überhaupt nicht bewusst sind" -> Ich bin mir des Fehlers bewusst, ignoriere das aber. (Das heißt nicht, dass ich es absichtlich mache.) Gib der Sprache noch ein paar hundert Jahre, und "ein" ist richtig.

Comment: Im Gesprochenen ist es mir egal, aber ausgeschrieben sieht das sooo kacke aus °v°

Comment: Leicht nicht, aber die einfache Regel ist "Wenn 'der', dann 'einen' - wenn 'das', dann 'ein'". Womöglich ist es am einfachsten, sich daran zu erinnern, daß man 'der Film' sagt und nicht 'das Film'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Faustregel ist so wie du sagst. Im Deutschen ist Nominativ und Akkusativ immer gleich, im Singular wie im Plural – nur Maskulina haben unterschiedliche Form:

Maskulin Singular:

```
Nom.     | Akk.
der Mann | den Mann
ein Mann | einen Mann
```

Comment: die Frau ist Nom/Akk (Nominativ oder Akkusativ). das Kind, Nom/Akk - Plural: die Männer/Frauen/Kinder Nom/Akk.

Comment: Von welcher Faustregel redest Du?

Comment: Wenn man die Formentabelle der schwachen Adjektiv-Deklination (nach der/die/das) anschaut, müßte eigentlich klar sein, was ich meine. So eine Tabelle muß man nicht lernen. Man kann sich die Tabelle nur mit -en denken und n fünf mal streichen.